# Is there any adverse effect to my feet if I wear running shoes all the time?

Tags: feet, musculoskeletal-system

Recently I bought a pair of running shoes (with a lot of cushioning) and another pair of casual shoes. However, the casual shoes didn't fit my feet well and I want to exchange them, which would take a few days. I'll go out on a trip tomorrow. I'm thinking about wearing the running shoes for the entirety of my trip. Would wearing running shoes all the time have adverse effects on my feet, since the extreme amount of cushioning might be "unnatural" in a sense?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I understand you asking if any type of acute or chronic musculoskeletal issues will arise due to wearing cushioned shoes during a trip.  If this is the question:

> **No this is perfectly fine.**  The cushioning will actually be beneficial if you're doing any type of extended walking.

The only case where this could cause any type of issue would be neglecting to use a medically prescribed orthotic *(this is a custom casted shoe insert)*.

Any reason you're thinking otherwise?

Comment: +1 *The cushioning will actually be beneficial if you're doing any type of extended walking.* [Citation Needed]. Otherwise excellent answer!

Comment: I just thought that maybe the soles are specially designed for running and might not be that suitable for prolonged walking, such as seemingly suggested by this article https://www.verywell.com/can-you-wear-running-shoes-for-walking-3436327. For example, the specific part of your foot that touches the ground first might differ when running compared with walking. But indeed perhaps those differences are minimal and too professional to make a difference.

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18577583   Plantar pressure reduction associated with running shoes.  @JIXiang I love questions related to gait analysis - feel free to post a new question and I'll gladly look into it for you!

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with the exact same issue many times, I can tell you that the only troublesome outcome of this would be your running shoes wearing out faster. For example, after 8 months instead of 12 - the exact figure heavily depends on your running / walking habits. As for your question, running with worn-out shoes can cause injuries.

It's not a bad thing to use running shoes for walking/hiking, as long as you take this fact into account. I do this all the time and replace my running shoes more often / use older ones for light walking/dancing.

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE, Adam. Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers), in order to provide the community with the means to assess the merit of the answer, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help].

Answer (score 1):

It was not specified what kind of "trip" is planned. Extreme weather, height (mountains), ground conditions are quite decisive variables to consider. Then of course there is also the length of the trip.

A 4 day business trip to a coastal [city](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/10/09/shoes-worst-for-feet_n_4069370.html) in temperate climate is very different to actually running in running shoes or to 6 months trecking through the jungle during the monsoon or the Alaskan Rockies in winter. Choose the right tool for the job.

[Most important](https://www.prevention.com/health/shoes-and-foot-pain) is of course [that the shoes do fit!](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26611985)

"Is there [*any* adverse](http://edition.cnn.com/2011/11/04/health/shoes-feet-hurt-body/index.html) effect to my feet if [I wear running shoes](http://www.netdoctor.co.uk/healthy-living/wellbeing/a26805/shoes-affect-you-health/) *all the time?*"

There needs to be some care taken, not only in choosing the shoes but also to your feet as such, to prevent these most common possible conditions:

- [blisters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blister)
- [athlete`s foot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athlete%27s_foot)
- [onychomycosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onychomycosis)
- [ingrown nails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ingrown_nail)
- [paronychia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paronychia)
- [immersion foot syndromes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immersion_foot_syndromes) like [trench](http://www.healthline.com/health/trench-foot#overview1) [foot](http://www.foot-pain-explored.com/trench-foot.html)
- [chilblains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chilblains)
- [subungual hematoma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subungual_hematoma) (tennis toe)
- [metatarsophalangeal joint sprain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metatarsophalangeal_joint_sprain)

While these possible conditions from that incomplete list may be a bit on the extreme side of "any adverse effects", they are certainly more probable with prolonged use of any shoe. It is still not very advisable to always wear the same pair of shoes. If one somehow has to make do with only one pair of shoes:
[Take the shoes off](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/19424280903204036) as often as possible, keep your feet dry, airy, clean, change the socks.